# How do I get the first IP and the last IP given any address (followed by its subnet mask) given any other address than the subnet's network address?

Tags: python, ip, subnet, cidr

The following code:

```
from ipaddress import IPv4Network

n = IPv4Network('192.168.18.100/24')

first, last = n[0], n[-1]
print(first)
print(last)
```

returns `ValueError: 192.168.18.100/24 has host bits set`
when given any other address from the subnet than its network address.

How do I get in Python the first IP and the last IP given any address (followed by its subnet mask) given any other address than the subnet's network address?

Comment: Use the `strict=False` argument to disable that check.